# Show JS and CSS code in Angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, format

In my Angular 1.x application (using ES5) I need to show the user the sample of formatted css and js code on the UI (with indentations, line-breaks, etc.), which the the user will need to copy and paste into his own html file. The sample of code:

```
<style type='text/css'> html, body { margin: 0 }
.banner {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
</style>
<script>
window.showSmth = function(item) {
   // some logic here
}
</script>
```

I've tried to search for some 3rd parties, but no results so far, could someone advice me on this?

Comment: You can use `<pre>`tag

Comment: try this simple integration for better visibility http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

Comment: `<code>A piece of computer code</code>`

Comment: This looks pretty straight-forward: https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML proper, there’s no way short of escaping the characters.

The only solution guaranteed to work everywhere is to escape the code (`<` and `&` as  `&lt;` and `&amp;`, respectively) manually.

1. Replace the `&` character with `&amp;`
2. Replace the `<` character with `&lt;`
3. Replace the `>` character with `&gt;`
4. Optionally surround your HTML sample with `<pre>` and/or `<code>` tags.

**Syntax highlighting sites:**

[rainbows](http://craig.is/making/rainbows) **(very Perfect)**

[prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

[syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/)

[highlight](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/)

[JSHighlighter](http://www.devpro.it/jshighlighter/)